# How to add silverlight app to Orchard CMS

Tags: silverlight, orchardcms

How to add silverlight app to site based on Orchard CMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a good starting point: http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Silverlight